# Export single strip in VSE

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, audio

I have one long audio strip in the V.S.E. and I split it into multiple pieces using hard cut, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Now I could delete the other strips and export one, and then make a new file, cut out the one I want, and so on and so forth and what have you. But as my run-on sentence describes, it would take to long. So how do I export a selected (audio) strip in the V.S.E.?

Answer (score -2):

mark the start frame and the frame track end as is rendering in the Properties window

[image]
[image]